# Does CP-ABE have any disincentive to share secret keys

Tags: encryption

I want to use a CP-ABE scheme to encrypt data to be accessed by multiple unknown (at time of encryption) users.

Reading the papers related to CP-ABE, there does not appear to be any disincentive for users to leak the secret keys they are given as the SK is not used by the user for signing or authentication.

Is this a valid interpretation or are there disincentives built into CP-ABE.